# How to convert nested loops to nested Streams?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have an int array and I want to find all pairs that sum to zero. In the old days I would do something like this:

```
public static int count(int[] a) {
    int cnt = 0;
    int N = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {

        if (a[i] + a[j] == 0) {
            cnt++;
        }
       }
    }
    return cnt;
    }
```

Now I'm having some trouble converting this to streams.

I tried the following approach but I get a IllegalStateException:

```
final IntStream stream1 = Arrays.stream(a);
final IntStream stream2 = Arrays.stream(a);
long res = stream1.flatMap(i -> stream2.filter(j -> (j + i == 0))).count();
```

Comment: The IllegalStateException is not my problem. I understand that. It was a consequence of my difficulty in translate the nested for to streams. My problem is how to convert the nested for in stream

Comment: plz edit the question then and I'll reopen in this case

Comment: @MLeiria I voted for reopening and changed the title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change `stream2.filter` to `Arrays.stream(a)` - the Stream would be closed the second time you would try to process it.

But you are not counting correctly anyway, it should be:

```
 IntStream.range(0, a.length)
          .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(a).skip(x + 1).filter(j -> j + a[x] == 0))
          .count();
```

Comment: That's it!!! Thanks. Didn't know about the `skip`. Still getting my head in Java 8 (which is great by the way)

Comment: I've got it. Thanks

Comment: Sure, @Eugene. Great stuff in the answers.

Answer (score 5):

**`Streams` are non-reusable** so you can't define them once and keep reusing. This is why storing them in variables is considered a bad practice.

You need to create them on the spot:

```
long res = Arrays.stream(a)
  .flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(a).filter(j -> (j + i == 0)))
  .count();
```

Also, in order to fully reflect the provided implementation and avoid duplicates, you would need to `skip` some elements at the beginning of each nested `Stream`:

```
long res = IntStream.range(0, a.length)
  .flatMap(i -> Arrays.stream(a).skip(i + 1).filter(j -> (j + a[i] == 0)))
  .count();
```

---

If you want to extract them to variables, you would need to use a `Supplier` which will serve as a factory for our `Streams`. Each `get` call creates a new `Stream` instance:

```
final Supplier<IntStream> s = () -> Arrays.stream(a);
long res = s.get()
  .flatMap(i -> s.get().filter(j -> (j + i == 0)))
  .count();
```

Comment: thanks. It does the trick with the difference that the stream approach counts repeatedly. In the nested for, the inside loop is one step ahead the outer loop, so it does't repeat the count. For instance if `int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3,4,-3,5,-5};` the nested for gives  a result of 2 which is correct because there are only two elements (3, -3) and  (5, -5) but the stream gives a result of 4

Comment: @MLeiria i will update the answer